# My iPhone's wi-fi receptor is dead. Is there a way to connect to internet on phone via USB or bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, wifi

My wi-fi connect button seems to have greyed out. Last time this happened the provider replaced the phone with a refurbished phone but it's not an option anymore as the phone is no longer under warranty.

Is there a way to have internet on my phone without using wi-fi?

Comment: I had that problem on my iPhone 4S. I could not find a solution and could only use cellular data. So I used cellular data until I upgraded to a newer iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+Fix+iPhone+4S+Wi-Fi+Grayed+Out/22167

I think you have to change the hardware. 'Cuz there's no way except Cellular Data.

Answer (score 0):

Any Mac running Mojave can share internet over USB. Open system preferences and in sharing turn on caching and/or internet sharing over USB.

Apple also sells a lightning to USB adapter that allows many USB to Ethernet adapters to work so you don’t need a Mac to get networking in that case, just two adapters and Ethernet.